# select in application give me an empty array but in database give rows(Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

My model:

```
public function getSolServicoById($id){

    $select = 'SELECT * FROM solicitacao_servico WHERE id_solicitacao = "$id" LIMIT 1';

    $query = $this->db->query($select);

    return $query->result();

}
```

My controller:

```
public function editaSolicitacao($id){

        $this->load->model('Pedido_Model','pedido');
        echo $id;
        $data = $this->pedido->getSolServicoById($id);
        print_r($data);

    }
```

When i select it on database i receive rows but when i select in application i get empty array and i don't know why it happen?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM solicitacao_servico WHERE id_solicitacao = '{$id}' LIMIT 1";
```

Also look forward to using prepared statements to reduce sql-injection vulnerability.

Comment: Good catch. The single quotes around the OP's query mean it won't be parsed for the $id variable.

Comment: I need wait 15 minutes for do that but i will. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zuqui if you use codeigniter's active record library as shown in below answer you won't have to face these problems and the parameters are also properly escaped by active record

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do this, just because its a simple query in CI is:

```
$this->db
     ->select('*')
     ->from('solicitacao_servico')
     ->where('id_solicitacao',$id)
     ->limit(1)
     ->get();
```

Doing it this way doesn't constrain your code to a particular database type (MySQL, MSSQL, etc) because it will create the correct syntax for your application with the built in active record feature.